# How to get a question migrated?

Tags: support, questions, migration

I asked a [question about extension/app/freeware options on a mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/287299/monitor-elements-of-a-webpage-receive-real-time-alerts) for a particular use case, and a user suggested I might be better off at Software Recommendations.

I didn't know about that site at the time of writing, but it seems like it might be a better fit. My question then is twofold; is my question actually better suited for that site? And if so, how do I go about getting it migrated?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ‘flag’ link under the question, choose ‘in need of moderator intervention’, then describe the problem including which site you would like the question migrated to and why.

[image: in need of moderator intervention]

In general on other Stack Exchange sites, this is usually not necessary. Instead, you would choose ‘close’/‘flag’, then ‘off-topic because’ ‘This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network’ and select the site from the list. Ask Different does not have any migration paths preconfigured, so a moderator is required to handle migrations manually, using the flag system described.

---

In terms of when to migrate though, there is an important rule of thumb:

> - **Don't migrate for the sake of migration**. We only migrate questions because they are off-topic on the original site. It is perfectly possible for a question to be on-topic on multiple sites, but that is not a reason to migrate it elsewhere, unless the OP requests migration. As a general rule, if someone asks a question here, and it's on-topic here, it should stay here.

[What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10249/222623)

Sometimes, though, Ask Different goes against this guideline — due to the low-traffic nature of some parts of this site, it may be beneficial to the question for it to be elsewhere. This is on a case-by-case basis and the guidelines on Meta.SE still take priority.

Answer (score 1):

Although the question is on topic here, I’ve migrated it away and asked (via a flag) for the comments to get cleared on the new site. If the migration is rejected, please flag for re-opening here.